# Can I switch searchable resource (xml) or searchSuggestAuthority in runtime?

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, searchview, searchable

My problem is that I'm switching from activities to fragments in a viewpager.

Each of the activities have declared something like this:

```
<meta-data
   android:name="android.app.searchable"
   android:resource="@xml/my_xml" />
```

The thing is that a fragment can't have that. Searchable is for activities but I want that when I'm switching in the viewpager my fragment, I want to switch the "android:resource" XML file too.

I know that there is this to set the searchable info:

```
searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
```

But is there a way to change "SearchableInfo > searchSuggestAuthority"? Is it possible? It's the only thing I'm interested in.

Thanks!